# Obsolete DMM fuses - what are safe substitutions?

Tags: protection, fuses, circuit-protection

I have two DMMs that need new fuses to measure current.

The first DMM is a small Radio Shack cheapie that wants a 5x20 mm 250V ceramic fast-blow 0.315 A, the second DMM is a Triplett 1101 A (still a bit of a cheapie) that needs a 5x20 mm 500 V ceramic fast-blow 0.3A.

I will only use these meters for guitar pedals and other small-signal, low-voltage measurements. The maximum external power supply that I can foresee would be ~18 V, 2 A.

Both meters have a 200 mA max on the fused probe connection, the Triplett has a 10 A unfused port, the Radio Shack only has 200 mA max, no unfused port.

I have looked at Amazon, Ebay, local electronics stores, [www.thefuseshop.com](http://www.thefuseshop.com), Triplett.com; I feel I have searched everywhere but it has been pointless. Mouser and DigiKey only carry 250 V ceramic fuses in that size, as far as I can tell.

For my application, would I be OK with a 0.3 A or 0.5A, 250 V ceramic fast-blow for the RS model and a 0.5 A, 500 V ceramic fast-blow for the Triplett? These seem to be plentiful.

Comment: I’d go for the 0.3A as 300mA is just under 315mA so that is a safe choice.

Comment: Here you go....      https://www.ebay.com/itm/354517951748?hash=item528aeaa504:g:vwkAAOSwy8Jjwe2a&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAsJMv4V%2Fq7EAG3wuOdULBC8LAKmW7fhq3ufMaFBkoFXifeULrLtAl7AxKBq5YuPmgyCERrMxHVDR9NrhahUaXO58t%2BbA0fsNHEyA%2BW1yXpOKVdxw6JEKdUy7g8f7MBpHaYDKiLkjl7RMjLMnEjmSd%2BejeWcT7y7%2BBO88BIk61vYZhnhn%2BbLvTKs4ZkJwMldX7bZlv1AC%2FoEG7vBl%2Bd0cbMJbJDUEP2f8niMVMjzsI9563%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7b54IfFYQ

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use it on small appliances (like guitar pedals) then you don't need ceramic fuses, you can just use glass fuses.

If you do use glass fuses I would recommend scraping of the `CAT II` or `CAT III` markings as with these substitute fuses the meter is no longer safe for use on mains circuits.

Comment: Thanks, this is good information.  I appreciate it.